# Opera Mobile for Windows + Reported Screen Size

Tags: opera, user-agent

I know this isn't a direct programming question, but's it's kinda relevant as I'm trying to get a good testing environment set up before I embark on my latest project.

I'm trying to set up [Opera Mobile for Windows](http://labs.opera.com/news/2010/04/22/) to allow me to test a new website. The UserAgent I get is a fairly generic one, so my workaround is to tweak my [mobile.browser](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/) file to have the correct screen width and height of the target device.

Is it possible to add to the list of "fake" user agents that Opera Mobile for Windows can pretend to be? It currently supports S60, Android and Windows Mobile.

Comment: Are you just trying to modify the value of the User Agent that Opera Mobile for Windows sends?

Comment: yes, just for testing purposes. I'd rather do that than have to change my mobile.browser file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify headers using Fiddler scripts. From the examples at http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp, here's a line that might be of particular interest:

> Pretend your browser is the GoogleBot webcrawler
>
> `oSession.oRequest["User-Agent"]="Googlebot/2.X (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)";`
>
> `OnBeforeRequest`